# ¿Por qué no se puede llamar onclick con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He intentado llamar a una función desde HTML a JQuery con `onclick`, pero no ejecuta. ¿Cuál es la razón?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function hola(){
alert("hola")
}
})
```

Comment: No está demás recordar que [se desaconseja usar manejadores de eventos inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). Aunque de hecho, no estás mostrando cómo estás haciendo la llamada a esa función.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: La función `hola()` está definida dentro del bloque `$(document).ready()`... debes definirla fuera del bloque para que sea accesible desde cualquier parte del código...

Comment: Revisá la última parte de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43797604) (ampliando lo que dice @Cris223511.dev )

Comment: Relacionado: [Evento onclick Jquery no toma (JS)](/questions/556551)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a utilizar el listener `.on("click", function())` de jQuery.

Para hacerlo funcionar solo tienes que agregar la clase `btn-hola` a un botón que tengas en el HTML.

```
$(".btn-hola").on("click", function() {
  alert("hola");
});
```

Espero que te haya sido de utilidad.

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que está pre-definido, quería saber por qué no funcionaba con el onclick del HTML

Answer (score 0):

El código que tengas dentro de `$(document).ready()` se dispara una vez carguen todos los elementos del DOM de tu HTML.

Entonces, en tu código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function hola() {
    alert("hola");
  }
});
```

Tu función `hola()` solo está definida dentro del ámbito de la función `$(document).ready()`, por lo que quiere decir que la función `hola()` solo es accesible dentro de esa función y no puede ser llamada desde otros lugares fuera de ella, incluyendo desde el atributo `onclick` en el HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function hola() {
    alert("hola");
  }
});
```

```html
<button onclick="hola()">Saludo</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
```

Ni tampoco invocando la función fuera del todo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function hola() {
    alert("hola");
  }
});

hola();
```

```html
<button onclick="hola()">Saludo</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
```

---

Una solución sería que una vez cargue toda la página, se defina la función `hola()` y luego asigne un listener con el evento `clic` al botón, indicando que al ser escuchado el evento en tu botón (es decir, cuando se haga clic en el botón), **invoque** la función `hola()` **dentro del mismo bloque**, ya que en ese bloque **la función fue definida** y puede ser accesible **desde ese mismo bloque**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Defino
  function hola() {
    alert("hola");
  }

  // Asigno evento clic al botón
  $("#btn").click(function () {
    hola(); // Invoco la función que está dentro de este bloque
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Saludo</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
```

Y con el atributo `onclick` en tu HTML, el problema sería que estás creando ya el elemento `button` con el evento `click` para que al ser clickeado llame a la función `hola()`, por lo que no tendría acceso al `$(document).ready(function ()` y no encontraría dicha función (como el ejemplo que te adjunté arriba). Lo único que se me ocurre es definir la función `hola()` en el ámbito global para que desde el propio evento `click` invoques la función ya definida, y aquí ya sería inutilizable el código jQuery:

```js
// Defino la función, lista para ser llamada
function hola() {
  alert("¡Hola!");
}
```

```html
<!-- al hacer click, invoco la función "hola()", que ya está definida previamente -->
<button onclick="hola()">Saludo</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema no es particular de `Jquery` es de javascript, en este lenguaje es posible que las funciones reciban como argumento otra función

```
$(document).ready(
  function () {        //  |-
      function hola(){ //  |
         alert("hola") // <   Esto es el argumento que se pasa a la función ready
      }                //  |
  }                    //  |-
)
```

Y un argumento "fijo" solo vive dentro de la función

Reduzcamos el problema para entenderlo mejor, digamos que tenemos este código

```
function suma10(num) { return num + 10}

suma10(32)
```

Como podrías acceder a ese `32`? pues solo puedes dentro de la función `suma10`, nunca desde fuera. Una manera de poder tener control sobre los argumentos es declararlos antes y no colocarlos fijos

```
function suma10(num) { return num + 10}

const unnumero=32;
suma10(unnumero);
```

Esta misma lógica aplica a tu caso:

```
function hola(){
   alert("hola")
}

$(document).ready(hola); // es hola sin "()", porque NO estamos invocándola, solo estamos pasándola como argumento por su nombre

//y luego en js
botonid.addEventListener("click", hola);

//o en jquery
// $("#idboton").click(hola)

//o en html
//<button onclick="hola()">
```